# Can't figure out Value of Type "ViewController' has no member 'averageIsAbove'

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I'm a newbie at Swift and I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong.

My test files says below-
 **Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'averageIsAbove'**

```
func testAverageIsAbove75(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) {
    XCTAssertFalse(testVC.averageIsAbove(a:76, b:75, c:71.9), "Average is below 75, it should return false."  )
```

MViewController file has this as the function:

```
func averageIsAbove75(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> Bool{
    if (a * b * c) / 3 > 75 {
       return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create a testVC instance or is your class called testVC?

Comment: I didn't create the testVC, it's part of our lab and I've been stuck on this for few days already.

Comment: Is 'MViewController' the actual name, or a typo? Have you imported your ViewController class into the tests using `@testable`?

Comment: Is 'MViewController' a typo, or is it the name? If it is the name, then instead of testVC.averageIsAbove75, you need to replace testVC with MViewController.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to make the method acessable to everyone. Add `class` before the keyword `func` to do so within your ViewController class.

Next, you're calling `testAverageIsAbove` but your function is called `averageIsAbove75`. Try changing the following:

```
 XCTAssertFalse(testVC.averageIsAbove(a:76, b:75, c:71.9), "Average is below 75, it should return false."  )
```

To this:

```
XCTAssertFalse(testVC.averageIsAbove75(a:76, b:75, c:71.9), "Average is below 75, it should return false."  )
```

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work. Still showing -Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'averageIsAbove'

Comment: make the function a public function

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not too sure how to do that, would you be so kind and explain it or show me?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: What is your class name of the view controller that has the averageIsAboive75 function? Is it MViewController?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController {
   func testAverageIsAbove75(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) {
       XCTAssertFalse(ViewController2.averageIsAbove75(a:76, b:75, c:71.9), "Average is below 75, it should return false."  )
   }
}


class ViewController2 {
   class func averageIsAbove75(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> Bool{
        if (a * b * c) / 3 > 75 {
           return true
        }
   else {
          return false
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: or remove the class before the func and make a instance of ViewController2 first in ViewController1 like let testVC = ViewController2(), but then you have to subclass the ViewController2 from some class with init